# Pausing GIF playback in java

Tags: java, swing, awt, gif

i'm attempting to control the playback of a GIF in Java. The GIF is an Image object, and as there appears to be no built in method for pausing, what I'm currently trying to do is run the wait() command on the Image object. However, the only way to do this is to use synchronize, which causes the whole program to hang.

The most obvious way around this issue is to break the GIF into separate frames, and display them sequentially only when not paused. however this seems rather arduos, so i ask, is there a simpler method to pausing a gif in java that I am missing?

thanks much.

Comment: `"...is there a simpler method..."`: not that I'm aware of.

Comment: From what I understand, you would need to load each sub picture yourself, determine the frame timing between each from and generate your own background controller to cause the images to change...so I agree with Hovercraft, no, there isn't a simple way...

Comment: well damn thats irritating. thanks for the responses.